# Writing simple for loop in 1 line in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to rewrite following java method into Kotlin function:

```
int C(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        result += C(i) * C(n - i - 1);
    return result;
}
```

How can I write it in one line? Something like:

```
tailrec fun C(n: Int): Int = if (n == 0) 1 else { /* for loop? */}
```

Comment: Maybe `tailrec fun C(n: Int): Int = if (n == 0) 1 else for (item in collection) print(item)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy your Java code into IntelliJ IDEA which can convert it to Kotlin code, you can then change `0..n - 1` to `0 until n` (thanks [fredoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252000/fredoverflow)), replace the for loop with [`sumBy{}`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-by.html), inline `result`, replace the `if` expression with return, and finally convert it to an expression body:

```
fun C(n: Int): Int = if (n == 0) 1 else (0 until n).sumBy { C(it) * C(n - it - 1) }
```

Note that this function is not eligible for [`tailrec`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#tail-recursive-functions) as the last operation is not a call to the function (`C`) but is a summing operation.

Comment: Brilliant. That's exactly what I was searcing for: (0..n - 1).sumBy{}. Thanks.

Comment: An alternative to `(0..n - 1)` is `(0 until n)`.

Comment: Good point @fredoverflow. I've my updated the answer. Thank you.